# Any complex roots for $\varphi(s)=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)+\sum_{n\ge0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, roots, computational-mathematics, analytic-continuation

It's known that when you analytically continue the Riemann zeta function to the complex plane, it has complex roots on a vertical line.

I would like to figure out if there are complex roots to the following analytic continuation of the function $\varphi(s)=\sum_{n\ge1} e^{-n^s}:$

$$ \varphi(s)=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)+\sum_{n\ge0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\zeta(-ns) ~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$

> Are there any complex roots for $(*)?$

> What does a complex plot of this function look like in a circular region centered at the origin with radius $r=30?$

$(*)$ converges for complex $s\ne0$ and for $\Re(s)<1$.

Since $(*)$ is quite complicated I'm having trouble analyzing it.

Comment: You shouldn't have $\varphi(s)=0$ because $\varphi$ is nonzero for $s>0$. But your two equations $\varphi=\Gamma+\Sigma$ and $-\Gamma=\Sigma$ do, obviously, imply $\varphi(s)=0$, so one of them must be wrong... Maybe show where you're getting these two equations from?

Comment: If you claim that the function is analytic, then by Picard little theorem the image of $\varphi$ is at least the complex plane minus a point. We should be really unlucky that this point is zero!!

Comment: You could as well use the logaritmic derivative of the function and integrating over some circle; if you manage to show this is positive you are done. There are formulas for the logarithmic derivative of both the zeta and the gamma function...

Comment: @runway44 It could be that $s < 0$. Numerically, it looks like there's a root around $s = -0.925$.

Comment: There are only two real roots: one around $s=-4.748$ and the other around $s = -0.925$.

Comment: @Varun I meant the two equations imply $\varphi(s)\equiv0$ **identically**, which obviously can't be true. OP, it's poor English to say "Does $\varphi(s)=0$?" with no specified value of $s$; you should phrase it as "Does $\varphi(s)=0$ have a solution?"

Comment: any ideas on finding complex roots?